# ASP.NET Deployment issue saving image to database

Tags: asp.net, image, iis, base64

I am having an unusual issue when I deploy my code from VS2015 to IIS. In VS when I run the web code, either as debug or release, the image I select and load then convert to base64 is converted to a byte array and saved to the database without any problems. However, when I deploy to the web server the code fails to work and the image is never updated. I am not getting any error information. As long as I run it from VS it all works. Is there something on the IIS server that needs to be configured? Any help or comments will be greatly appreciated.

HTML CODE

```
<form class="input-group" id="img2b64">
<input id="inputFileToLoad" name="files" type="file" 
onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" />
</form>
<!-- is used to display b64 code and hold the b64 for ajax call to controller -->
<textarea id="b64" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

JQUERY CODE

```
 function encodeImageFileAsURL(cb) {
        return function () {
            var file = this.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function () {
                cb(reader.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }

    $('#inputFileToLoad').change(encodeImageFileAsURL(function (base64Img) {
        $('#act_Photo').attr('src', base64Img);
        $('#b64').val(base64Img);
    }));
```

IN THE CONTROLLER CODE

```
// model.ImageFile is the base64 string
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ImageFile))
{
     // strip out base64 header
     int pos = model.ImageFile.LastIndexOf(',') + 1;
     string data = model.ImageFile.Substring(pos);
     // get byte array of base64 image
     byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
     // convert and save as byte array to DB
     var acctImg = new WebImage(bytes).Resize(220, 200, false, true);
     // aRec.Photo is in DB record
     aRec.Photo = acctImg.GetBytes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all is well. I restarted the site in IIS. Seems to have been a caching issue causing all the grief. Sometimes I just hate caching.